# what is the opposite of "appreciate"?

Tags: word-choice

What is the opposite word for "appreciate" that I can use in a sentence like this one :-

"If you like my work I would be happy if you appreciate it. If you do not like my work, you have the right to __________ it."

Comment: You have the right to *criticise* it!

Comment: For the sake of "balance", you might consider ***deprecate*** here (in other contexts, ***depreciate*** is an antonym, but not in this context). But I suspect you haven't fully understood the meaning of ***appreciate*** (it doesn't exactly mean ***praise, extol***).

Comment: Perhaps **disparage** .

Comment: In the context you have, "like" and "appreciate" are synonyms.

Comment: I cannot for the life of me figure out what it is your example sentence is supposed to mean. “If you like my work, I would be happy if you appreciate[d] it” ***makes no sense*** to me. As Hote Licks says, it means, “If you like my work, I would be happy if you liked it”, which is tautologous to the point of being nonsense. “If you don’t like my work, you have the right not to like my work” would be the opposite, and that obviously makes no more sense.

Comment: I concur with Janus, but perhaps the OP means something like "praise/recommend" versus "criticize/pan".

Comment: Much depends on the meaning you have in mind for the word _appreciate_ in your example. The nearest thing to an opposite of _appreciate_ in the sense of "think well of" might be _despise_, while a better opposite of _appreciate_ in the sense of "be grateful for" might be _resent_. It seems to me that _appreciate_ is a remarkably slippery word.

Comment: "If you like my work I would be happy if you **promote** it. If you do not like my work, you have the right to **ignore** it."

Answer (score 2):

Your answer would be "disparage". The definition means the opposite of appreciate. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Your answer would be a lot more useful if you would include a source :)

Comment: To follow up on oerkelens's suggestion, I recommend not only that you identify a reputable online or print source that supports your contention, but that you also include the relevant definition of _disparage_ from that  source, linking to it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

***Disapprove*** would be an option.

> 1. To have an unfavorable opinion of; condemn.
> 2. To refuse to approve; reject.

Answer (score 1):

Did a quick search for `antonym appreciate`.

[Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/appreciate) says

- be critical
- criticize
- decrease
- depreciate
- disparage
- disregard
- lose value
- neglect
- overlook

In your context, `depreciate` and `disparage` would work, although it is a little unusual to request this treatment, unless you are [Monty Python](http://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=monty%20python%20this%20is%20abuse&FORM=VIRE1#view=detail&mid=91D6EEF5DB411C250F1991D6EEF5DB411C250F19).

Comment: So why isn't this question general reference?

Comment: Good question, Edwin. Some of the antonyms fit well, some less so. I would not say "you have the right to decrease it"; neither "you have the right to overlook it." The OP seemed to require a little direction.

Answer (score 0):

"Appreciate" is generally something that happens passively: someone who appreciates a work takes pleasure in it, recognizes its quality, and learns from it, without necessarily contacting the author.

If you do insist on an antonym, I'd suggest "disparage" instead of "deprecate" (which is a term of art regarding computers, meaning "mark as not to be used, with the intention of removing later"). But I think that a better phrasing (at least in American English) would be something along the lines of, "If you see anything you like or dislike, please let me know."

Answer (score 0):

I would say they have the right to ***ignore*** it, going neutral rather than negative.

But if you want negative, @rajah9's *deprecate* would be my choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you said 'malign' that would allow them to disparage your work but tell them clearly how wrong they were if they did.

> **Malign**  (verb used with object)
>   1. **to speak harmful untruths about**; speak evil of; slander; defame:

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/malign)

Answer (score 0):

"Ignore" or "criticize" would work in the second sentence, but the first sentence is your real problem.  You need an active verb there, such as "support" or "praise". I assume "appreciate" is not a euphemism for "leave a donation"?